# GNOME extension Executor does not save config

Tags: 20.04, gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I have recently installed the [Executor extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2932/executor/) on Ubuntu 20.04 to have  some text displayed on the top bar. The problem is that the config does not get saved after I make some changes to the commands. Even when I add a new command, Executor does not show it.

The default command is `echo Executor Works!`. Even when I change one word, let's say change the command to `echo Executor DDDD!`, it does not get saved.

How can I make the commands in Executor get saved and displayed on the top bar?